# Is it possible to develop a application to coomunicate with routers using PHP and KAA server?

Tags: iot, kaa

Is it possible to create a IOT application using PHP?

Iam looking forward to develop a web intercaste to handle some routers and devices using KAA server.

Appreciate any advices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaa does not support PHP, so it's impossible to create a PHP application.

If you need to create a web application, you can set up a server on Java, C++, or other language supported by Kaa, create application there and communicate with it by php curl, javascript, or something like this.

Or you can store a Kaa application on the same server and use it by `exec()` or `system()` commands.